# How to install VLC in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: system-installation

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 and want to install VLC media player on it but i don't know how to install that on my Ubuntu desktop. Could any one help me sort out this problem

Answer (score 58):

To install VLC from the Ubuntu repositories, open your terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install vlc
```

Comment: @Abbas4master Yup, if you happen to be a new user, do not fear the command line and use it whenever you can, even for something simple like installing programs found in the official repositories. You will get used to it in no time.

Comment: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/06/install-vlc-3-0-ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

Its also in the ubuntu software center. so you should be able to install it from there as well. if you dont feel like using command line.

Comment: software center was stuck at 'installing'

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is great using the command line, but for those who need to use the GUI way, in your menu find your software installer (menu item "system tools," then "software"), then in the new Gnome Software Center search for VLC and then click "install."  Hope this is also helpful to someone.